What is the product of all integers?
I recently wondered whether $\prod_{a\in \mathbb{Z}} a$ is defined and if so, what it is. I constructed the following reasoning.
Let $(A_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of sets such that $ A_n \subseteq A_{n+1} $ for all $ n \geq 1$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} A_n = \mathbb{Z}$ in the sense that for every $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ there exists an $N_a\geq 1$ such that $n\geq N_a$ implies that $a\in A_n$.
Then $P_n=\prod_{a\in A_n} a$ is defined for all $n\geq 1$. Further, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P_n=0$, since for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies that $|P_n|<\epsilon$, namely $N_0$.
Now the question is of course whether $\prod_{a\in \mathbb{Z}} a= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \prod_{a\in A_n} a$ for an arbitrary such sequence $(A_n)$ following the conditions described above. I would argue that it is, and that it in fact is the only sensible way to define the product of all integers, since (as far as I know) that's (at least equivalent to) how sums over countably infinite sets are defined.
I'm eager to get your input on this!

The product of an infinite set (as opposed to sequence) does not have a universally accepted definition.  But certainly the product of any sequence containing all the integers diverges to zero; and the product of any sequence containing all the non-zero integers diverges to $\pm\infty$.

It is possible to compute a countable product, much the same as it is to compute a countable sum, however even among countable sums there are those which do not converge to any finite limit (e.g., $\sum_n 1/n$ or even simply $\sum_n n$). Likewise, the infinite product $\prod_n n$ does not converge to a finite limit (the product $\prod_n 1/n$ converges to $0$).
Your construction with the sets $A_n$ and their products $P_n$ is reminiscent of another fact in analysis, which is that for a bi-indexed sequence $a_{m,n}$ it does not always hold that
$$\lim_{m\to\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty} a_{m,n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \lim_{m\to\infty} a_{m,n}$$
Taking the product over each finite set, then passing to the limit in the family of sets vs taking the limit first, then the product; it is not universally guaranteed that these two processes should yield the same result (in fact they do not, as you have observed: $0$ on the one hand vs $\infty$ on the other).

Thank you. Are you claiming that the product of all integers does not converge? I would like to see a reasoning for that. I think you may misunderstand me; my conclusion is that the product is 0. My framework for determining this is identifying $\prod_{a\in\mathbb{Z}} a = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \prod_{a \in A_n} a$, which I have showed is 0 if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} A_n=\mathbb{Z}$ in the sense I described in the post. If you disagree with my conclusion, it would like to see what alternative frameworks lead to different conclusions, or why my framework isn't sensible to begin with.

The product of all integers does not converge because the sequence of partial products $\prod_{n=1}^N n$ diverges to infinity. Your identity is incorrect, because the left hand side is infinity while the right hand side is zero.

Why do you think that it matters how $\prod_{n=1}^N n$ behaves? This is the different framework I'm asking about.

OP is taking the product of all integers including zero, not just $n\geq 1$.
